# Passing byte buffer across JNi but not able to see bytebuffer elements

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to send bytebuffer from Java to JNI layer. I am getting void* pointer on JNI without error. But I am not able to see in debug is the elements that are present in ByteBuffer or just print the bytebuffer contents accessed in JNI.
 Basically, I wanted to cross verify if I am getting bytebuffer correctly and after that I am converting that to std::byte* about which I am not sure if right or not because of no expertise on this and also no resources I could get for same.

So, this is the code I am working on:

in Java side:

```
    byte[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.length);
    buffer.put(array);
```

Passing the bytebuffer->buffer to JNI and then doing this on JNI as I have received ByteBuffer as jobject:

```
void* inputPtr = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(byte_buffer);

   jlong capacity = env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(byte_buffer); //Works fine returns 4
    std::byte* data;
    data = static_cast<std::byte *>(inputPtr); //Working without error
```

Is this correct way to assign std::byte* data to inputPtr and also how can I check contents of byte_buffer, when I am getting inputPtr. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems OK. What exactly is the problem? NB the `rewind()` seems pointless.

Comment: Agree with marquis, I want to add that you shouldn't tag the question with all the tags you know of. Make it specific.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, what are contents of ByteBuffer, how can I check that. Please see edited message: I have removed rewind(), makes sense. How to see contents of ByteBuffer as I have kept it in std::byte* in JNI. How to check what's in it in JNI. Couldn't find out any method to check  the same.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, Can you tell me how to check contents for same in JNI?

Comment: You could always print them. I can't see your debugger.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo040/c/recipeNo040_PassByteBuffer.c - maybe that's what you are looking for.